# Determining Values for Cube Roots of Unity Expression

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

It is required to determine the possible values for $1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}$ where $n$ is a natural number and $\omega = -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. The following identities are given; $\omega^{4}=\omega$ and $\omega^{2}+\omega+1=0$

My attempt:

Consider the expression for even $n$, $n=2k$ $$ 1+\omega^{n}+\omega^{2n}=1+\omega^{2k}+\omega^{4k}$$ $$ 1+\omega^{n}+\omega^{2n}=1+\omega^{k}+\omega^{2k}$$

Now for odd $n$, let $n=2m+1$ $$1+\omega^{n}+\omega^{2n}=1+\omega^{2m+1}+\omega^{4m+2}$$ $$1+\omega^{n}+\omega^{2n}=1+\omega^{m+2}+\omega^{2m+1}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here. I have just be testing some values for $n$ on my caluclator and it seems that the value of the expression is independent of whehter $n$ is even or odd so there must be a different method for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As $w^3=1,$ the length of the period of $w^n$ is $3$

For any integer $m,n$ can be one of $3m+1,3m+2, 3m$

**Case**$\#1:$

If $n=3m+1\equiv1\pmod3, 2n=2(3m+1)\equiv2\pmod3$

**Case**$\#2:$

If $n=3m+2\equiv2\pmod3, 2n=\cdots\equiv1\pmod3$

**Case**$\#3:$

What if $n=3m?$

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying but I am not well familiarised with this topic involving the mod notation so this hint is not very useful to me.

Comment: @SwissGnome, no issue. If $$n=3m+1,w^n=?, 2n=3(2m)+2, w^{2n}=?$$

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. $\omega^{n}=\omega(\omega^{3m})$ and $\omega^{3m}$ will always be one. Then $\omega^{2n}=\omega^{6m+2}=\omega^{2}(\omega^{3m})^{2}$ so $\omega^{n}=\omega$ and $\omega^{2n}=\omega^{2}$. Is this correct?